# Angular 8 Route to another component in new window on grid row action and pass entire row

Tags: c#, .net, angular, typescript, angular8

On select action from grid, I want to open another component in new tab. At the same time I want to pass entire row data so that another component is loaded with data when opened in new tab.

I tried following:

```
//redirects and load new component data correctly but opens in current tab instead of new tab

navigate(row: ExampleRow){
this.router.navigate(['/new-page/1'], {state: {data: {row}}}); } 

//open new component in current window loaded with data but opens component with empty data in new tab as well
navigate(row: ExampleRow){
this.router.navigate([]).then(result => {  window.open('/new-page/1', '_blank'); }); }

// Throws error
<a [routerLink]="['/new-page', row.id]" [state]="{ data: row }" >Navigate</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you open a new tab the two web pages are separate and the state doesn't carry over.

```
navigate(row) {
  localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(row));
  window.open('/new-page/1', '_blank');
}
```

another.component.ts

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.localTemp = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data'));

  // here you can choose to keep it in the localStorage or remove it as shown below
  localStorage.removeItem('data');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for prompt response. I have sensitive data in the row so is it safe to store in local storage ?

Comment: No, it would not be safe, If you want to communicate between both windows or tab you can implement some sort of server side communication.